# Finding an appropriate scalar

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the following integral
$$a_N\int_0^\infty{\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+T_{N-1}(2x)}}dx=1$$
Where $T_N=\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{x^k}{k!}$
I'd like to find the value for $a$ which makes this true for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$.  The trivial cases where $N=1$ yield

$$a_0\int_0^\infty{\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}}dx=a_0\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=1 \Rightarrow a_0=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

And if we take the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}a\int_0^\infty{\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+T_{N-1}(2x)}}dx=a_N\int_0^\infty{\frac{2e^x}{2e^{2x}}}dx=a=1$$

But how would I go about finding the value of $a$ for specific $N$?  I would assume that any value of $a_N$ would have to satisfy $1<a_N<\frac{2}{\pi}$, so there are upper and lower bounds, but how can I hone in on specific $a_N$?

Comment: What is $ T_N $?

Comment: Oops...sorry.  I added it just now.

Comment: You should write $a_N$, shouldn't you ?

Comment: Quite trivially $$I_N = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(2x)^k}{k}}\,dx$$ decreases as $N$ increases.

Comment: I understand, but are there methods in order to find specific scalars that make the integral equal to 1?